# How to update table, with selected values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to update the field TAG in accountinfo table with the value ABCD with results of a select like query in a diferent table of the same DB. 
The query doesn't return any errors, but neither update.

```
UPDATE accountinfo  
SET TAG= 'ABCD' 
WHERE 'ABCD%' IN (select NAME from hardware where NAME LIKE 'ABCD%');
```

---

```
select NAME from hardware where NAME LIKE 'ABCD%'

ABCDABELCHIOR
ABCDABELMARQUES
ABCDAG200CX1
```

Comment: Is there any common column in account info and hardware?

Comment: Which rows in `accountinfo` do you want to update? (The only column from `accountinfo` we are shown any information about is named `TAG`. We see that the `hardware` table has a column named `NAME`, and some of the values start with `'ABCD'`. You've identified rows in  the `hardware` table. But we don't how rows in `hardware` table are related to rows in `accountinfo`. You need to back the cart up, back behind the horse, and figure out how to distinguish the rows in `accountinfo`: which rows you want updated, and which rows you don't want updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IN` operator is an equality comparison. Your use of the **`'%'`** in the string literal makes it look as if you want to some sort of `LIKE` comparsion... matching the first four characters.

The predicate in the `WHERE` clause of your query is going to evaluate to either TRUE or FALSE, for *every* in the `accountinfo` table, no matter what the row in `accountinfo` contains.  You're either going to update none of the rows, or *all* of the rows.

Which rows in `accountinfo` do you want to update?

Is there any "matching" of rows in `accountinfo` with rows in `hardware`? How are you going to know if the rows "match"?

---

EDIT:

***There are no rows that match accountinfo in hardware.***

So, the information we have to go on: there's a column named `TAG` in the `accountinfo` table. And that's the only column we know about.

There is a column named `NAME` in the `hardware` table. And there are rows in the table with `NAME` values that begin with **`'ABCD'`**.

Again, *which* rows in `accountinfo` did you want to update? How are you going to identify which rows to update?

Comment: There are no rows that match accountinfo in hardware. What I need is that TAG field in the table accountinfo gets updated with ABCD if the NAME field in hardware starts with ABCD.

Comment: All the rows where NAME starts with 'ABCD'

Comment: @Ebar: You've shown "All the rows (**from `hardware` table**) that have a `NAME` that starts with `'ABCD'`". You show an example of four rows. But those rows (from the `hardware` table) are separate and distinct from rows in the `accountinfo` table. You need some way to *identify* the rows in `accountinfo` you want to update. (Rows from the `hardware` table aren't telling us *anything* about *which* rows in `accountinfo` need to be updated.)

Comment: There is an ID row wich matches both databases in account info, that matches HARDWARE ID. Can I use that to match them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found your error: 
you have to write:

```
UPDATE accountinfo  
SET TAG= 'ABCD' 
WHERE TAG IN (select NAME from hardware where NAME LIKE 'ABCD%');
```

This will update all tags, that are in the names of hardware and begin with 
abcd.

Comment: Still get no rows affected.

Comment: Then you have no hardware with a name starting with ABCD

Comment: Yes I do, you can see the result of a select query in my question